# Does web VR mode no longer work in Safari on iOS13?

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari

I have a website that creates a vr experience using the device accelerometer that no longer works on Safari in ios13. Does anyone know if this feature was removed? I know in iOS12 it was moved behind a Safari setting, but that setting is no longer available in iOS13. Oddly, it does still work using the chrome browser on iOS13.

Answer (score 0):

They removed to option in the settings page, and introduced an api instead.
Which is better because now the user gets a dialog asking the user for permission instead of having to go into the settings.

```
function onClick() {
    // feature detect
    if (typeof DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission === 'function') {
      DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission()
        .then(permissionState => {
          if (permissionState === 'granted') {
            window.addEventListener('devicemotion', () => {});
          }
        })
        .catch(console.error);
    } else {
      // handle regular non iOS 13+ devices
    }
  }
```